# Rails 3.2 ActiveRecord Queries with Multiple Joins

Tags: activerecord, join, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an issue trying to properly join table data and rendering it into a view.  I am currently designing a system so my restaurant clients can create dynamic menus and display them properly on the menu page. Currently I have a Menu, MenuItem, and Section models.  I have successfully created forms where I can assign menu_items to menus and associate a menu_item with a section.  My issue is rendering the front end menu.  I want my menu to look like the following template.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Menu Name
  First Section
    Menu Item
    Menu Item
    ...
  2nd Section
    Menu Item
    Menu Item
  ...
```

My models and associations are listed as follows.

in Menu.rb

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menu_menu_items, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :menu_items, :through => :menu_menu_items
```

in MenuItem.rb

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menu_menu_items
  has_many :menus, :through => :menu_menu_items
  belongs_to :sections
```

in Section.rb

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menu_items,  :dependent => :nullify
```

So far in my view I have the following.  This is where I truly lack the understanding of how Rails and ActiveRecord work so I can properly create this view.  One thing I also need to know is that if a Section has no menu_items for a particular menu,  how do I exclude it?

```
<div class="content">

  <% @menus.each do |menu| %>
    <h3><%= menu.name %> <br/></h3>
    <% Section.all.each do |section| %>
      <b><%= section.name %><br/></b>
      <% menu.menu_items.each do |menu_items| %>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= menu_items.name %> <br/>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

<--------------------------------------------------------- **Edit** ---------------------------------------------------------------->

I now have the following code working.  This gives me the sections and the corresponding menu items that only belong to the particular menu.  The only thing left that I need help on is the code still outputs an empty section if no menus have items in that section.  Any guidance?

```
<% @menus.each do |menu| %>
  <h3><%= menu.name %> <br/></h3>
  <% Section.all.each do |section| %>
    <b><%= section.name %><br/></b>
    <% menu.menu_items.where(:section_id => section.id).each do |menu_items| %>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= menu_items.name %> <br/>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

<---------------------------------------------------------**Edit 2**---------------------------------------------------------------->

I was able to derive the SQL I needed in order to pull the sections belonging to a particular menu.  How do I implement it?

```
select count(sections.id),sections.name
from menu_items 
  join menu_menu_items on menu_items.id=menu_menu_items.menu_item_id
  join menus on menus.id=menu_menu_items.menu_id 
  join sections on menu_items.section_id= sections.id 
where menu_id=16  #for example.
group by sections.id;
```